# CUDA customized atomicCAS for floating point types (like double)

Tags: c++, cuda, atomic, compare-and-swap

`atomicCAS` allows using integral types of various lengths (according to specs word sizes of 16/32/64 bit).
It works fine for integral types like `int`, `unsigned long long`,...

I want to use atomic operations for non integral types of same length.
My naive thought is to simply type-cast the data to an integral type of same length like `double` to `uint64_t` (`unsigned long long`). To avoid implicit conversion I do it via a pointer.

**Example**

```
double cmp = 0.0;
double val = 4.6692016091;
double dst = 0.0;
uint64_t old = atomicCAS((uint64_t*)&dst, *((uint64_t*)&cmp), *((uint64_t*)&val));
```

**Problem**

Threads quit as soon as the `atomicCAS` command is executed. I couldn't find any details **why** that happens.

Is there a way to use `atomicCAS` that way in CUDA context?

In case it's relevant:
I use CUDA 11.7, `--machine 64` nvcc switch and `compute_61,sm_61` (Pascal architecture).

Comment: In regular ISO C++, `*((uint64_t*)&cmp` would be a strict-aliasing violation (undefined behaviour).  But if you used `memcpy` into local `uint64_t` temporaries, and used `uint64_t dst` (with memcpy type-punning in other readers and writers), that would be legal C++.  (Of course ISO C++ has `std::atomic<double>` with a working `.compare_exchange_weak()` member function, so you don't actually need to do that in plain C++).  Anyway, IDK if CUDA is like gcc/clang `-fno-strict-aliasing`, in which case I'd have expected this to work.

Comment: There is an example in the cuda programming guide how to use atomicCAS to implement custom atomics

Comment: Please post the entire test kernel. I just tried looking at the PTX code for a sample I made and it looks correct. You didn't try to to use a local variable for ```dst```, did you? Because atomicCAS is only defined for global and shared memory. Also note that PTX uses strongly typed memory addresses and registers. The resulting assembly looks very awkward

Comment: @Homer512, yes indeed isolating a minimal example to solve another issue, I used a thread local variable as in  the example above. What you describe makes perfect sense, since there is no value in atomic operations in a non concurrent scenario indeed. A compiler hint would have been great, but I know from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Homer512 pointed out, `atomicCAS` is implemented for `global` and `shared` memory, as it makes no sense in non concurrent scenarios (like thread local variables used in the example above) to use atomic operations (at least I can't think of any).

Following vectorized example works instead.

```
const unsigned int idx = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
const unsigned int nThreads = 64;
if (idx >= nThreads) return;

__shared__ double s[nThreads];
const double cmp = s[idx] = 0.0;

double val = 4.6692016091;
uint64_t old = atomicCAS((uint64_t*)&s[idx], *((uint64_t*)&cmp), *((uint64_t*)&val));
```